# How to create a MQL4 function that returns the largest losing trade?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I am trying to create an Expert Adviser (EA) in MQL4 language.

How to code a function that returns the largest losing trade, (and not the total losing trades)?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/205233)

Comment: please provide a minimal working example and more details of what you need. I think you are wanting to loop through your open trades till you find the ticket with the largest profit loss and then return that ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return the ticket of the largest loss trade.

With a default of `loss = DBL_MAX`, this can still return profitable trades with the lowest profit.
With a **`loss = 0`**, it will only return a trade with the most negative profit or zero.

Will return a ticket of such trade and EMPTY, if no trades found.

```
int LargestLoss( int magic, double loss = DBL_MAX )
{
        int ticket=EMPTY;
        for(int i=0; i < Orderstotal(); i++)
        {
                if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
                {
                        if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==magic && OrderProfit()+OrderSwap()+OrderCommision()<loss)
                        {
                                loss=OrderProfit()+OrderSwap()+OrderCommision();
                                ticket=OrderTicket();
                        }
                }
        }
        return ticket;
}
```

Comment: loss should be double not integer value I am afraid, otherwise it could be a problem with detecting the correct ticket, if you check -1.99 then -1.01, your code decide -1.01 is the largest

Comment: @DanielKniaz Good point, wrote it in a hurry. Changing now

Comment: what is DBL_MAX?
Is it a variable that i have to declare for the function to work?

Comment: @NicolaBastienne max value a double can be https://docs.mql4.com/constant_indices

Comment: You might already know, that the proposal to return as a ticket number a 0 is not a responsible option. Returning a value of **`EMPTY`**, instead of 0, is a way safer practice, as a blind `OrderSelect( aTicketNUM, ... )` will **remain safe & robust** against any naive blind & unhandled-exception generated products.

Comment: You might have already realised, that **`OrderProfit()` is not showing the real profit / loss** and might want to update your answer.

Comment: @user3666197 Good suggestions, updated my answer to include them

Answer (score 0):

### An actual Net Profit of any order has 3 components to add:

for a fair comparison, one ought add all [A] + [B] + [C] to compare one against the others:

```
                        double aNetLOSS     = OrderProfit()     // [A]
                                            + OrderCommission() // [B]
                                            + OrderSwap();      // [C]
```

A robust calling-interface ought provide

For a serious MQL4 automation, the returned value **ought be always avoding any unwanted side-effects**:

```
bool GetTheTicketWithLargestLOSS(       int    &aTicket2SEARCH,
                                        double &aValueOfLOSS,
                                  const string  aSymbol2SEARCH, // <= _Symbol
                                  const int     aMagNUM        = 0,
                                  const int     aSearchMODE    = MODE_TRADES // | MODE_HISTORY
                                  )
{
    double aLocalMaxLOSS  = 0.;
           aTicket2SEARCH = EMPTY;         // BLOCK ANY BLIND OrderSelent() USE

    for ( int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++ )
    {         // TRY:
            if (        OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS, aSearchMODE ) )
            {
                  if (  OrderSymbol()      == aSymbol2SEARCH    // MATCH?
                     && OrderMagicNumber() == aMagNUM           // MATCH?
                        )
                  {     double aNetLOSS     = OrderProfit()     // [A]
                                            + OrderCommission() // [B]
                                            + OrderSwap();      // [C]
                        if (   aNetLOSS    <  aLocalMaxLOSS )
                        {
                          aLocalMaxLOSS     = aNetLOSS;         // UPDATE
                          aLocalTkt2FIND    = OrderTicket();
                        }
                        continue; // ----------------------------^ LOOP NEXT
                  }
                  continue; // ----------------------------------^ LOOP NEXT
            }
            else
            { // ON EXC:
              // LOG:
              // REPORT:
              // HANDLE:
              // RET/SIG:
                 return( False );            // SIG TERM EXIT
            }
    }
    aTicket2SEARCH = aLocalTkt2FIND;         // ON  FAIR EXIT: FINAL ASSIGNMENTS
    aValueOfLOSS   = aLocalMaxLOSS;
    return( True );                          // SIG FAIR EXIT ( &DATA SET )
}
```